# Deadlock and schema modification lock

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have a deadlock that I need some input for

```
<deadlock>
<victim-list>
<victimProcess id="process4c86a61868" />
</victim-list>
<process-list>
<process id="process4c86a61868" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 5 SECURITY_CACHE($hash = 0x5:0x0)" waittime="2364" ownerId="15082818710" transactionname="SEC Cache Coherency" lasttranstarted="2020-09-25T13:05:02.643" XDES="0x245ed33d320" lockMode="Sch-M" schedulerid="16" kpid="8184" status="suspended" spid="172" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2020-09-25T13:05:02.550" lastbatchcompleted="2020-09-25T13:05:02.550" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.550" clientapp="[Shadow NDO Session 00000189]" hostname="CTXVDA-005" hostpid="15024" loginname="Domain\AOS-DK" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="15082818429" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
<executionStack>
<frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_grantdbaccess" line="80" stmtstart="4280" stmtend="4458" sqlhandle="0x0300ff7fae2d27c39e78130137a5000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
select @owner_uid = principal_id from sys.database_principals where name = @name_in_db </frame>
</executionStack>
<inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 32767 Object Id = -1020842578] </inputbuf>
</process>
<process id="processb97f92c928" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 5 PERMISSIONS(class = 0, major_id = 0)" waittime="2365" ownerId="15082818573" transactionname="read permissions" lasttranstarted="2020-09-25T13:05:02.640" XDES="0x178bed2d930" lockMode="Sch-S" schedulerid="20" kpid="12996" status="suspended" spid="188" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2020-09-25T13:05:02.637" lastbatchcompleted="2020-09-25T13:05:02.630" lastattention="2020-09-25T13:04:55.993" clientapp="Microsoft Dynamics NAV Classic client" hostname="CTXVDA-003" hostpid="56896" loginname="Domain\EGC-ES" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="15069357664" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671156320" clientoption2="128058">
<executionStack>
<frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="114" sqlhandle="0x02000000f4611a06e91ca2d53472b55965ad7e0b91ac18440000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
SELECT FROM "SOME_DATABASE_NAME"."dbo"."COUNTRY_S$Purchase Line" WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) WHERE "Document Type"=@P1 AND "Document No."=@P2 AND "Line No."=@P3 AND (("Document Type"=@P4)) AND (("Document No."=@P5)) OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) </frame>
<frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_execute" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f47dacef5010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
sp_execute </frame>
</executionStack>
<inputbuf>
(@P1 int,@P2 varchar(30),@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 varchar(30))SELECT FROM "SOME_DATABASE_NAME"."dbo"."COUNTRY_S$Purchase Line" WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) WHERE "Document Type"=@P1 AND "Document No."=@P2 AND "Line No."=@P3 AND (("Document Type"=@P4)) AND (("Document No."=@P5)) OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) </inputbuf>
</process>
<process id="process54bff4ccf8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 5 SECURITY_CACHE($hash = 0x5:0x0)" waittime="2365" ownerId="15082818576" transactionname="SEC Cache Coherency" lasttranstarted="2020-09-25T13:05:02.640" XDES="0x1606e8f6da0" lockMode="Sch-M" schedulerid="28" kpid="12548" status="suspended" spid="527" sbid="1" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-09-25T13:05:02.527" lastbatchcompleted="2020-09-25T13:05:02.527" lastattention="2020-09-25T13:00:18.717" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server" hostname="SQL-07" hostpid="2784" loginname="LinkedBISQL" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="15082801850" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
<executionStack>
<frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_columns_100_rowset" line="9" stmtstart="340" sqlhandle="0x0300ff7f773d64f24d80150137a5000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
select
TABLE_CATALOG = s_cv.TABLE_CATALOG,
TABLE_SCHEMA = s_cv.TABLE_SCHEMA,
TABLE_NAME = s_cv.TABLE_NAME,
COLUMN_NAME = s_cv.COLUMN_NAME,
COLUMN_GUID = s_cv.COLUMN_GUID,
COLUMN_PROPID = s_cv.COLUMN_PROPID,
ORDINAL_POSITION = s_cv.ORDINAL_POSITION,
COLUMN_HASDEFAULT = s_cv.COLUMN_HASDEFAULT,
COLUMN_DEFAULT = s_cv.COLUMN_DEFAULT,
COLUMN_FLAGS = s_cv.COLUMN_FLAGS,
IS_NULLABLE = s_cv.IS_NULLABLE,
DATA_TYPE = s_cv.DATA_TYPE, -- Used by Katmai+ clients
TYPE_GUID = s_cv.TYPE_GUID,
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH= s_cv.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH = s_cv.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH,
NUMERIC_PRECISION = s_cv.NUMERIC_PRECISION,
NUMERIC_SCALE = s_cv.NUMERIC_SCALE,
DATETIME_PRECISION = s_cv.DA </frame>
</executionStack>
<inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 32767 Object Id = -228311689] </inputbuf>
</process>
</process-list>
<resource-list>
<metadatalock subresource="SECURITY_CACHE" classid="$hash = 0x5:0x0" dbid="5" id="locka1e4fe2500" mode="Sch-M">
<owner-list>
<owner id="process54bff4ccf8" mode="Sch-M" requestType="wait" />
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process4c86a61868" mode="Sch-M" requestType="wait" />
</waiter-list>
</metadatalock>
<metadatalock subresource="PERMISSIONS" classid="class = 0, major_id = 0" dbid="5" id="lock708d967580" mode="Sch-M">
<owner-list>
<owner id="process4c86a61868" mode="Sch-M" />
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="processb97f92c928" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait" />
</waiter-list>
</metadatalock>
<metadatalock subresource="SECURITY_CACHE" classid="$hash = 0x5:0x0" dbid="5" id="locka1e4fe2500" mode="Sch-M">
<owner-list>
<owner id="processb97f92c928" mode="Sch-M" />
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process54bff4ccf8" mode="Sch-M" requestType="wait" />
</waiter-list>
</metadatalock>
</resource-list>
</deadlock>

I am wondering why process id="processb97f92c928 would need a schema modification lock

<metadatalock subresource="SECURITY_CACHE" classid="$hash = 0x5:0x0" dbid="5" id="locka1e4fe2500" mode="Sch-M">
<owner-list>
<owner id="processb97f92c928" mode="Sch-M" />
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process54bff4ccf8" mode="Sch-M" requestType="wait" />
</waiter-list>
</metadatalock>
```

Its a select statement so Im kind of surprised that its claiming such a broad lock. Would the hints in the statement trigger such a behavior ? The system has replication configured but not for this table. I have checked that we do not have any triggers on table this table

The deadlock is recurring. What would a logical way of troubleshooting this be ?

Comment: I doubt if there is a simple answer to this as locks are involving SECURITY_CACHE. I saw [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/128763/deadlock-and-schema-modification-lock.html) and few other blogs not an actionable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the very bottom of the deadlock event I can see that all 3 processes involved are waiting for **Schema modification lock (Sch-M)** which is acquired upon the execution of a DDL statement, and in such a case the read uncommitted isolation level that spid 188 is executed due the table hint is disregarded. The key point here is to **identify the DDL command**.
You have mentioned that there are no triggers but triggers are related to DML operations that can lead to blocking due to the Serializable isolation level they impose but this is not the case here, a DDL command is the key point.

Comment: it seems like this part is always a participant of the deadlock.

`code`
<frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_grantdbaccess" line="80" stmtstart="4280" stmtend="4458" >
select @owner_uid = principal_id from sys.database_principals where name = @name_in_db </frame>
`code`
new users is being created throug the application. could a large number of users created in the system contribute to this issue ?

select count() from master.sys.database_principals --1450
select count() from USERDATABASE.sys.database_principals --1065